# Python os.system invalid syntax

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04

Hi I would like to execute the following command via shell.

```
 curl -g -d '{ "action": "block_count" }' [::1]:7076
```

However when inserted in an os.system call , I get an invalid syntax. What would be the right syntax format.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import json

aba = os.system('curl -g -d '{ "action": "block_count" }' [::1]:7076')

baba = json.loads(aba)
```

Comment: Could you include the syntax error you are getting?

Comment: Remember to properly escape nested quote marks.

Comment: You can use triple-quotes: `os.system('''curl -g -d '{ "action": "block_count" }' [::1]:7076''')`.

Comment: Don't use shell out to `curl` to make an HTTP request; use a Python library like `requests`.

Comment: Failing that, don't use `os.system`; use the `subprocess` module instead.

Comment: `os.system()` creates problems for you because it needs a string that can be parsed as a shell command. `subprocess.call(['curl', '-g', '-d', '{ "action": "block_count" }', '[::1]:7076'])` passes each argument as a separate Python string, with no shell involved -- so you don't need to worry about shell-safe quoting.

Comment: @Ted, I've updated my answer with a `subprocess` example, and also fixed a bug in `requests` invocation - initially I used `GET` method, instead of `POST`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use the [triple-quoted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings), like:

```
os.system('''curl -g -d '{"action": "block_count"}' [::1]:7076''')
```

but even better, use the **right tool for the job**, i.e. [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
import requests
data = requests.post('[::1]:7076', json={"action": "block_count"}).json()
```

---

If you insist on direct `curl` command invocation, please use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module instead of the old and inflexible [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) (also unsafe, for inputs not strictly checked). You can use the [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) as a [replacement in your case](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module). There's no need to execute your `curl` command in a subshell, so you can split `curl`'s arguments, like:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(['curl', '-g', '-d', '{"action": "block_count"}', '-s', '[::1]:7076'])
data = json.loads(output)
```

Note that `check_output` will return the standard output of the command executed (like `os.system` does), but it'll raise a [`CalledProcessError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError) exception in case the command fails with non-zero status, or [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) exception if the command is not found.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen()` without `shell=True` is an intermediate step that might be worth adding -- better than `os.system()`, worse (but, perhaps, more broadly applicable) than `requests`.

Comment: I was in doubt should I mention the `subprocess` as a replacement for `os.system`, since I wouldn't recommend neither over `requests`. But it makes sense to emphasize that `os.system` is deprecated. I'll add it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the single quotes. So change this:

`aba = os.system('curl -g -d '{ "action": "block_count" }' [::1]:7076')`

to this:

`aba = os.system('curl -g -d \'{ "action": "block_count" }\' [::1]:7076')`

Comment: or alternatively use bigger quotes for the outside string. `'''` or `"""`